# Hiding the error message for time and date input fields

Tags: javascript

```js
$("#tym").keydown(function() {
  if (!($(this).val())) {
    $('#error5').html('<p style="color:red;font-size:14px;"align="center">Enter time</p>');
  } else {
    $('#error5').html('');
  }
});

$('#sal').keyup(function() {
  if (!($(this).val())) {
    $('#error6').html('<p style="color:red;font-size:14px;"align="center">Enter salary</p>');

    $('#sal').focus();

  } else {
    $('#error6').html('');
  }
});

$('#sald').keyup(function() {
  if (!($(this).val())) {
    $('#error7').html('<p style="color:red;font-size:14px;"align="center">Enter Salarydate</p>');

    $('#sald').focus();

  } else {
    $('#error7').html('');
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </br>
  </br>


  <form method="POST" align="center" id="ins">
    </br>


    <label>Available Time:</label>
    <input type="time" name="availabletime" id="tym" />
    <span id="error5"></span>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Salary:</label>
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="sal" />
    <span id="error6"></span>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Salary Date:</label>
    <input type="date" name="salarydate" id="sald" />
    <span id="error7"></span>
    <br/><br/>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter" />
  </form>\
```

Context:
This is code for a form validation.The validation is working but i want to hide the error message for time and date when clicking the corresponding field.All other feilds validation is working including error message hiding.I changed the function keydown to mouseup ,but not working.Is there any function like keyup for input fields for time and date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) that will call your error handling when the input is changed

```
$("#tym").on("input", function() {
  if (!($(this).val())) {
    $('#error5').html('<p style="color:red;font-size:14px;"align="center">Enter time</p>');
  } else {
    $('#error5').html('');
  }
});
```